# How to store the result of my function in parent variable in JS?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, variables, constants

I have a little problem here.
My console.log(e) gives me the good result (1 or 2).

but the console.log(test) return me the integer variable.
how can I store the function result in the test variable to use it later please ?
Thx a lot !

```js
const spans = selectPager.getElementsByTagName('span');

const test = function() {
  for (let i = 0, len = spans.length; i < len; i++) {
    (function(e) {
      spans[i].onclick = function() {
        console.log(e)
      }
    })(i);
  }
}
test();

console.log(test);
```

Comment: Your function doesn't seem to be returning anything. Could you explain what you want to store?

Comment: If you use a snippet then please also use the _"Tidy"_ button before you close the editor

Comment: I want to store the result of the console.log(e).
spans[i].onclick = function(){
          console.log(e)
 Sorry i'm a complete beginner :).

Comment: You can't store a value in `test` when you click the span that *travels back in time* (!!) so it is available to the `console.log(test)` you have at the bottom of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Pass a callback to `test`, and invoke the callback inside the click handler. There's also no need for the IIFE inside the loop, since you're using `let`:

```js
const spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');


const test = function(cb) {
  for (let i = 0, len = spans.length; i < len; i++) {
    spans[i].onclick = function() {
      console.log(i)
      cb(i);
    };
  }
}
test((result) => {
  console.log('Outside, have', result);
});
```

```html
<span>click</span>
<span>click</span>
<span>click</span>
<span>click</span>
<span>click</span>
```